# HTML5 Canvas transparency weirdness with pngs

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, transparency

I'm trying to apply transparency to some `ImageData` retrieved from a `canvas`. Simple, right? Just set an appropriate value to every fourth datapoint... only, it only seems to work with pixels that don't have pre-existing alpa values.

```
//create 2 canvases
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
document.body.appendChild(canvas);
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.id = "tempCanvas";
var canvas2 = document.createElement("canvas");
document.body.appendChild(canvas2);
var ctx2 = canvas2.getContext("2d");
canvas2.id = "tempCanvas2";

//draw the png in the first canvas
var testimg = document.getElementById("testimg");
ctx.drawImage(testimg, 0, 0, 200, 200);

//helper function to opacity to the pixels
opacity = function(pixels, value){
    var d = pixels.data;
    for(var i=0;i<d.length;i+=4){
        d[i+3] = value*255; //scale by 255
        if(d[i+3] > 255) d[i+3] = 255; //clamp
    }
    return pixels;
}

//make the first canvas' image data opaque
var data = ctx.getImageData(0,0,200,200);
data = opacity(data, 0.5);
//draw to second canvas
ctx2.fillStyle="#900";
ctx2.fillRect(0,0,200,200);

//should get a jsfiddle logo overlayed on red background
//instead, get yucky grey background
ctx2.putImageData(data, 0, 0);
```

(It's a little hard to reproduce because of same-origin policy, but here's a fiddle that uses the png jsfiddle logo: http://jsfiddle.net/97c0eetr/ )

Why does this opacity algorithm not work for the jsfiddle logo (and my other transparent pngs that I'm testing on http://localhost)?

Edit: FF42 Ubuntu, if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've hit the big endian / little endian issue : On most of today's computers/devices, the endianness is little endian, meaning that for a 32 bit value, byte order is 3-2-1-0.

So the opacity, which is the 4th byte (index 3) will be found at `pixelIndex * 4 + 0` ... == `pixelIndex * 4`.

Just change, in your code, your opacity function to :

```
opacity = function(pixels, value){
    var d = pixels.data;
    for(var i=0;i<d.length;i+=4){
        d[i] = value*255; //scale by 255
        if(d[i] > 255) d[i] = 255; //clamp
    }
    return pixels;
}
```

updated fiddle here : 
http://jsfiddle.net/97c0eetr/5/

The best 100% solution of course is to have two opacity function that you choose depending on endinannes of the browser. But by betting on little endian, you cover like 99% of the devices.

If you want to know endianness, i once made a small gist to get it, find it here : 
https://gist.github.com/TooTallNate/4750953

Here's the code :

```
function endianness () {
  var b = new ArrayBuffer(4);
  var a = new Uint32Array(b);
  var c = new Uint8Array(b);
  a[0] = 0xdeadbeef;
  if (c[0] == 0xef) return 'LE';
  if (c[0] == 0xde) return 'BE';
  throw new Error('unknown endianness');
}
```

And by the way, your function could simplify to

```
opacity = function(pixels, value){
    value = Math.floor(value * 255);
    if (value>255) value = 255;
    var d = pixels.data;
    for(var i=0;i<d.length;i+=4){
        d[i] = value;
    }
    return pixels;
}
```

---

Edit : So why the background isn't red ? -->> When using `putImageData`, you are using a raw 1 pixel for 1 pixel copy method. So everything gets replaced, whatever, for instance, the `globalCompositeOperation` or any setting. So the red background is just overwritten by the new data.

Solution is to `putImageData` on a temporary canvas -it will be written with the right opacity-, then to `drawImage` it on your target canvas, so that the opacity is taken into account for the draw.

Since you already had two canvases, change was easy, see updated fiddle here :
http://jsfiddle.net/97c0eetr/4/

Comment: Mind blown. But then, why in the updated fiddle is the background not red?